# jtable data insert to excel

Tags: java, jtable

Anyone have an idea how to insert data to existing excel file from jtable am using java to develop this program and my scenario is like this, jtable data insert to excel but the excel already have a design and formula. I don't know how to start it so I ask question. thank you for your tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to extract data from JTable. You this method:

```
public Object[][] getTableData (JTable table) {
    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    int nRow = dtm.getRowCount(), nCol = dtm.getColumnCount();
    Object[][] tableData = new Object[nRow][nCol];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nRow ; i++)
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nCol ; j++)
            tableData[i][j] = dtm.getValueAt(i,j);
    return tableData;
}
```

Now having data you can append them into excel file using apache poi. Here are tutorials  http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html

Comment: am going to insert the data to exciting excel file?

Answer (score 2):

Excel uses a complicated formatting for its native .xls files but it also supports other formats. I am using the Tab-Separated Values (TSV), which is commonly used for transferring information from a database program to a spreadsheet.

You can use below code to extract data from Jtable and export it to excel.

```
public void toExcel(JTable table, File file) {

try {
    TableModel model = table.getModel();
    FileWriter excel = new FileWriter(file);

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        excel.write(model.getColumnName(i) + "\t");
    }

    excel.write("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            excel.write(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString() + "\t");
        }
        excel.write("\n");
    }

    excel.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
  }
}
```